# configure: Specify a path to search in for headers AFTER the default paths

Tags: unix, makefile, compilation, configure, automake

To add a path to search in for header files, you can feed an `-I` argument to `configure`. However, the added path will then be searched in *before* the default ones, effectively overriding the default ones in case of duplication. I want a path to “fall back to” when headers are not available in default paths while still using default headers as much as possible. Is there any way to specify a path to search in for headers after the default paths? Or, for the ultimate purpose, is there any other way round? Like

- Setting the “search order” for paths; or
- Specifying the additional path with “low priority,” etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gcc` you might be successful using [`-idirafter`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#index-idirafter). Keep in mind though that `configure` may modify your search path with `-I` on its own, for example when it finds a library in a custom location, it might (and probably will) add `-I` for this location to all subsequent tests and final compilation, which might still include other packages from this new location if they are available there instead of default location.

Comment: I’ve tried and `-idirafter` works for `clang` as well. Really great to know!

Answer (score 0):

As you stated specifying the path using that flag will add it to the beginning of the include/library path. One possible work-around would be to add your custom library paths to your `ld.so.conf` file. This article goes over [Library path in gcc](https://transang.me/library-path-in-gcc/) various commands/environment variables to help you do so.

> By default, /etc/ld.so.conf refers to the content of all files in the directory /etc/ld.so.conf.d. You can look into the directory to control the configuration.